# Next.js 14 with styled-components setup not rendering browser vendor prefixes

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, next.js, styled-components

It's Next.js 14 and styled-components( added using .swcr ) clean setup, vendor prefixes are missing.
It should be automatically added yet it's not.

I have tried multiple fixes from internet, including adding custom **postcss.config.js**.
and **autoprefixer**, adding **browserlist** to package.json is not working either.

any ideas? Thanks.

### package.json - versions

```
"next": "^14.0.3",
"styled-components": "^6.1.1"
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
"postcss": "^8.4.31",
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  },
```

### postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

### Current

[image: what is rendering]

### What I want to achieve in runtime render

[image]